# What is the difference between following sql queries for SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server NOLOCK keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107314/sql-server-nolock-keyword)

What is the difference between these sql queries?

1. SQL query:

   ```
   SELECT 
   U.ID_USER AS ID,
   U.USERNAME AS NICK,
   U.PASSWORD AS PASS
   FROM T_USERS AS U WITH (NOLOCK)
   ```
2. SQL query:

   ```
   SELECT 
   U.ID_USER AS ID,
   U.USERNAME AS NICK,
   U.PASSWORD AS PASS
   FROM T_USERS AS U
   ```

Comment: Short answer: the former will *try* to avoid locking rows, and therefore may read data that's in the middle of being updated.  Long answer: Google "database locking" and read; it's the subject of dissertations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one (query with nolock) will not be blocked even if the data it is reading is locked exclusively and could return the rows which are not yet commited. If reading uncommitted data is not issue then NOLOCK is sually used to reduce blocking. Nolock specify that when reading the data do not try to take locks on resources like table,row,page.

The second one(query without nolock) will be blocked if any of rows are going under modifications or are locked exclusively.It will never read the data which is not yet commited as it will be blocked by the process which is changing the data. This is ususally when you do not want to read the data which is uncommited and where accuracy is of utmost importance.

Comment: When can be locked? When I use a query with "NO LOCK"?

Comment: No lock means it will not be blocked by any other process as this process is not trying to take any locks(as you specified nolock). By default process usually takes the shared lock on the resources like table,page or row.